# Copy files to different location based on file headers

Tags: powershell

I am trying to achieve the same result, but getting some strange behavior I am unable to solve by myself.

It only filters out the first `if`, then treats the rest as `else`. Does not matter how many different `if...else` I put in there, then it still only filters out the first `if`, then treats others as `else`.

I have also tried moving the headers around, so the once normally being treated as `else`, would be the first `if`, but is still only runs the first `if`.

```
[string] $FileDirectory = "C:\temp\Move by header\input";
[string] $OutputPathHeat = "C:\temp\Move by header\HeatMeter";
[string] $OutputPathWater = "C:\temp\Move by header\WaterMeter";
[string] $OutputPathOther = "C:\temp\Move by header\Other";

foreach ($FilePath in Get-ChildItem $FileDirectory | Select-Object -     
ExpandProperty                 
FullName)
{
    [string] $Header = Get-Content $FilePath -First 1

    if ($Header -match '#serial-number;device-identification;created;value- 
                   data- 
                   count;act-duration,second(s),inst-value,0,0,0;avg- 
                   duration,second(s),inst-value,0,0,0;energy,Wh,inst- 
                   value,0,0,0;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,0.*') {
        Move-Item $FilePath $OutputPathHeat
    } elseif ($Header -match '#serial-number;device- 
     identification;created;value-data- 
                       count;fabrication-no,,inst- 
     value,0,0,0;datetime,,inst- 
                       value,0,0,0;volume,m3,inst-value,0,0,0.*') {
        Move-Item $FilePath $OutputPathWater
    } else {
        Move-Item $FilePath $OutputPathOther
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your regex against headers with some regex testing tool?

Comment: No, because for me this is like showing a caveman a space-shuttle :)
I am not sure how to use a regex I just learned what is (from your advice), but not how to implement it in this case.

But this tool could be very helpful, I am trying to find some sort of log file where I can see what happens behind the curtains.

Comment: The code you posted is broken. Please do not wrap your code in arbitrary places when asking a question. Create a [mcve] that exposes the problem you want to troubleshoot, then copy/paste *that* code into your question *exactly as it is in your script*.

Comment: Will remember that this is my first question in here, and had a hard time figuring out how to get the editor to accept my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you are perhaps not showing us enough of the possible headers, I think you are trying to use `-match` on just about the whole first line.

Also, in your code, you break up the strings and even the commands quite haphazardly making the code and regexes really unreliable.
It would make more sense to focus only on the **differences** that distinct one file from the other and match on those.

Have a look at below code:

```
$RootDirectory   = 'C:\temp\Move by header'
$InputDirectory  = Join-Path -Path $RootDirectory -ChildPath 'input'
$OutputPathHeat  = Join-Path -Path $RootDirectory -ChildPath 'HeatMeter'
$OutputPathWater = Join-Path -Path $RootDirectory -ChildPath 'WaterMeter'
$OutputPathOther = Join-Path -Path $RootDirectory -ChildPath 'Other'

# get an array of Full path and filenames of the files in the input directory. 
# because you want files only, add the '-File' switch.
# if you're on PowerShell version below 3.0, use:
# (Get-ChildItem $InputDirectory | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer })
foreach ($FilePath in (Get-ChildItem $InputDirectory -File) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName) {
    $Header = Get-Content $FilePath -First 1

    # test for a string in the header line that distincts it from the other files
    if ($Header -match ';energy,Wh,') {
        # the substring ';energy,Wh,' defines this file as a 'HeatMeter' file
        Move-Item -Path $FilePath -Destination $OutputPathHeat
    }
    elseif ($Header -match ';fabrication-no,,') {
        # the substring ';fabrication-no,,' defines this file as a 'WaterMeter' file
       Move-Item -Path $FilePath -Destination $OutputPathWater
    }
    else {
        # if both key substrings above did not match, move to the 'Other' directory
        Move-Item -Path $FilePath -Destination $OutputPathOther
    }
}
```

Instead of using the `if..elseif..else` construction as above, using the `switch` command can make your code more readable and also it makes it easier for you to add extra tests in between.
Besides that, `switch` also has a `-Regex` parameter, so there is no need to write out `if ($Header -match ...` each time. You can read all about it here: [about_Switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-6)

The `if..elseif..else` block above could then be written as:

```
# test for a string in the header line that distincts it from the other files
switch -Regex ($Header) {
    # the substring ';energy,Wh,' defines this file as a 'HeatMeter' file
    ';energy,Wh,' { Move-Item -Path $FilePath -Destination $OutputPathHeat; break }

    # the substring ';fabrication-no,,' defines this file as a 'WaterMeter' file
    ';fabrication-no,,' { Move-Item -Path $FilePath -Destination $OutputPathWater; break }

    # if both key substrings above did not match, move to the 'Other' directory
    default { Move-Item -Path $FilePath -Destination $OutputPathOther }
}
```

Note: if the substrings you want to match against have characters that have special meaning in Regular Expressions, make sure you [Escape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-escapes-in-regular-expressions) them using syntax `[Regex]::Escape(the string to match against)`

Comment: That did the job and simplified a lot of my work. This approach is much more flexible to use now and going forward.

Much appreciated.